# How to create a wrapper for only a single specific component in styleguidist?

Tags: reactjs, react-styleguidist, styleguidist

In the Styleguidist documentation I found the example for creating a wrapper that will wrap every one of my components.  It looks something like this:

**styleguide.config.js:**

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
...
  styleguideComponents: {
    Wrapper: path.join(__dirname, 'src/styleguide/Wrapper')
  }
...
}
```

However I need to wrap one of my components a little differently and the wrapper I want to create should not be applied to any of the other components.  What would the code look like for this?   One wrapper that is applied to all my components and a specific wrapper that is applied to only one of my components?